# Backendless Library Error

Tags: ios, swift4

Estoy tratando de usar el programa de ejemplo de Backendless para iOS, para hacer el login, registro.

Y obtengo el siguiente error

> libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
>       0x108590b64 <+0>:  movl   $0x2000148, %eax          ; imm = 0x2000148 
>       0x108590b69 <+5>:  movq   %rcx, %r10
>       0x108590b6c <+8>:  syscall 
>   ->  0x108590b6e <+10>: jae    0x108590b78               ; <+20>
>       0x108590b70 <+12>: movq   %rax, %rdi
>       0x108590b73 <+15>: jmp    0x108587b00               ; cerror_nocancel
>       0x108590b78 <+20>: retq
>       0x108590b79 <+21>: nop
>       0x108590b7a <+22>: nop
>       0x108590b7b <+23>: nop

apenas bajé el programa hice

```
$ pod install
```

Comment: Hola Marcelo, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the following to make sure you're using the latest version of the pod:

```
$ pod update
```

Comment: Hi Mark, this is the spanish version of StackOverflow, so please translate your answer.

Comment: libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
    0x1141dfb64 <+0>:  movl   $0x2000148, %eax          ; imm = 0x2000148 
    0x1141dfb69 <+5>:  movq   %rcx, %r10
    0x1141dfb6c <+8>:  syscall 
->  0x1141dfb6e <+10>: jae    0x1141dfb78               ; <+20>
    0x1141dfb70 <+12>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x1141dfb73 <+15>: jmp    0x1141d6b00               ; cerror_nocancel
    0x1141dfb78 <+20>: retq   
    0x1141dfb79 <+21>: nop    
    0x1141dfb7a <+22>: nop    
    0x1141dfb7b <+23>: nop

Comment: Gracias Mark por tu respuesta ... ejecute el   "$ pod update" ,  se actualizaron todas las librerías, pero, obtengo el mismo resultado.

Comment: Lo siento, no hablo español, entonces usaré google translate. Me disculpo si la traducción sonará graciosa. @Marcelo, ¿podría mostrar cómo se ve la llamada API? Además, avíseme qué versión de Xcode usa.

Comment: Gracias Mark , la version que estoy usando es Version 9.4.1 (9F2000).  
Saludos

The version that Im using is 9.4.1 ...   
Regards,
Marcelo

Comment: Backendless.sharedInstance().userService.login(loginField.text, password: passwordField.text, response: { user in
                if self.stayLoggedInSwitch.isOn {
                    Backendless.sharedInstance().userService.setStayLoggedIn(true)
                }
                else {
                    Backendless.sharedInstance().userService.setStayLoggedIn(false)
                }

Comment: por favor, compruebe el depurador si se invoca el bloque "success" o "error".